# Docker redis container, gives Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: docker, redis

I start the redis container using the following command

```
docker run --name my-redis-container -p 127.0.0.1:6379:6379 -d redis
```

When I check the status of the running containers I see

> ```
> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
> a2c34209e079        redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 hours ago        Up 17 hours         127.0.0.1:6379->6379/tcp  my-redis-container
> ```

Now when I run a program on my host machine (Windows) and try to connect to the redis container I get the following error

> ```
> setUpConnection Redis error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
>     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1104:14)
> ```

I get this error using other programs as well, for example redis-commander

Comment: Have you tried with `-p 6379:6379`?

Comment: Yes I did, this is what I get on container ls

19df95c82edc        redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 seconds ago      Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   my-redis-container10

When I run the application I get the same error as ECONNREFUSED

Comment: From windows, what does `telnet localhost 6379` return?

Comment: Check the Windows firewall if there's a rule to allow 6379 port, if doesn't exists create it...

Comment: the telnet command failed with the following

Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 6379: C
onnect failed

firewall
I enabled port 6379 inbound and outbound for TCP traffic and I still get the same error.

Comment: How is docker installed? What does `echo $DOCKER_HOST` show?